# why this function returns a link_type but it was declared as iterator

Tags: c++, stl

This is a member function that was declared in list.h（GNU STL 2.9  list.h）

```
iterator begin() { 
return (link_type)((*node).next); }
```

and *link_type* is

```
template <\class T> struct __list_node
```

However,the *iterator* is

```
template<\class T, class Ref, class Ptr> struct __list_iterat
```

The part of `list.h` are following

```
template <class T, class Alloc = alloc>
class list {
  protected:
    typedef void*                           void_pointer;
    typedef __list_node<T>                  list_node;
    typedef simple_alloc<list_node, Alloc>  list_node_allocator;
public:      
    typedef T                   value_type;
    typedef value_type*         pointer;
    typedef value_type& r       eference;
    typedef const value_type&   const_reference;
    typedef list_node* l        ink_type;
    typedef size_t              size_type;
    typedef ptrdiff_t           difference_type;

public:
    typedef __list_iterator<T, T&, T*>             iterator;
    typedef __list_iterator<T, const T&, const T*> const_iterator;
}
```

And the part of `__list_node` are following

```
template<class T, class Ref, class Ptr>
struct __list_iterator {
  typedef __list_iterator<T, T&, T*>             iterator;
  typedef __list_iterator<T, const T&, const T*> const_iterator;
  typedef __list_iterator<T, Ref, Ptr>           self;

  typedef bidirectional_iterator_tag iterator_category;
  typedef T value_type;
  typedef Ptr pointer;
  typedef Ref reference;
  typedef __list_node<T>* link_type;
  typedef size_t size_type;
  typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
  link_type node;
}
```

They are different type at all!??,why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__list_iterator` has the implicit converting constructor `__list_iterator(link_type)`. It constructs an iterator from a node pointer: implicit `return (link_type)((*node).next)` is equivalent to explicit `return iterator((link_type)((*node).next))`.

You are watching a very old GNU STL. The current one has explicit constructor:

```
explicit
_List_iterator(__detail::_List_node_base* __x) _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
: _M_node(__x) { }

iterator
begin() _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
{ return iterator(this->_M_impl._M_node._M_next); }
```